# i have the problem to import dash to html

Tags: html, css, django, group-by

```py
def dashboard_view(request):
    clients = Client.objects.values('nom', 'tot_presta')
    data = Data.objects.values('client', 'tot_net')
    rdv = RDV.objects.values('client', 'item')

    df_clients = pd.DataFrame(list(clients))
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
    df_rdv = pd.DataFrame(list(rdv))

    ventes_par_client = df_data.groupby('client')['tot_net'].sum().reset_index()
    ca_par_technicien = df_rdv.groupby('client')['item'].sum().reset_index()

    fig_ventes_clients = px.bar(ventes_par_client, x='client', y='tot_net', title='Ventes par Client')
    fig_ca_techniciens = px.bar(ca_par_technicien, x='client', y='item', title="Chiffre d'affaires par Technicien")

    app = DjangoDash('dashboard_app')
    app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H1(children='Analyse des Ventes'),
        dcc.Graph(
            id='ventes-clients',
            figure=fig_ventes_clients
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            id='ca-techniciens',
            figure=fig_ca_techniciens
        )
    ])

    dash_content = app.index()
    context = {'dash_content': dash_content}
    return render(request, 'ManagerSalon360/dashboard.html', context)
```

i received this error to my terminal

```
Internal Server Error: /ManagerSalon360/dashboard/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MonLogiciel\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\MonLogiciel\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\MonLogiciel\ManagerSalon360\views.py", line 263, in dashboard_view
    dash_content = app.index()
AttributeError: 'DjangoDash' object has no attribute 'index'
[07/Jan/2024 22:35:20] "GET /ManagerSalon360/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78946
```

i using dash==2.9.3

dash-bootstrap-components==0.13.1

dash-core-components==2.0.0

dash-html-components==2.0.0

dash-renderer==1.3.0

dash-table==5.0.0

distlib==0.3.8

Django==3.2.23

django-asset-definitions==1.0.0

django-bootstrap4==23.4

django-cors-headers==4.3.1

django-dashboards==0.1.7

django-extensions==3.2.3

django-plotly-dash==2.2.2

django-redis==5.4.0

dpd-components==0.1.0

dpd-static-support==0.0.5

Comment: i tried 


    dash_content = app.index()
    context = {'dash_content': dash_content}
    return render(request, 'ManagerSalon360/dashboard.html', context)
But i received amlost de same error